# about recursions in lists

Tags: list, scheme, racket

```
(define (some n)
  (cond
    [(empty? n) false]
    [(cons? n)
     (+ (first n) 1)]))
```

I am having problems with the recursion. It adds 1 to the first element of the list. How would I add it to the rest of the list and combine the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your code, you have to get right the template for traversing an input list and building an output list as an answer:

```
(define (some n)
  (cond
    [(empty? n)                ; if the list is empty
     empty]                    ; return the empty list, not false!
    [else                      ; if it's not empty, then it's a list
     (cons (+ (first n) 1)     ; cons the new element
           (some (rest n)))])) ; and advance the recursion
```

The basic steps are always the same: ask if the list is null, `cons` the current element, advance the recursion over the rest of the list. The specific details will change depending on the problem, but the above template will get you on the right track most of the time. Now the result will be a new list with all of its elements incremented by one:

```
(some '(1 2 3 4 5))
=> '(2 3 4 5 6)
```

Comment: Does Racket have [TRMC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call#Tail_recursion_modulo_cons) optimization by any chance?

Comment: @WillNess It seems that not, I can't find a reference to it in the documentation. Maybe some of the developers that visit this site can enlighten us?

Comment: reason I ask, we see such code as you posted here (and I too, perhaps, elsewhere), but it works well *only* under TRMCO. So either we need to stress this every time, or the implementors need to give it to us poor users, finally. Prolog has it. Why not Scheme?

Comment: @WillNess know the audience: most of these guys posting questions are just learning about programming and are not that concerned about efficiency yet. In a professional environment it's very relevant to ask ourselves if our solution is optimal, but for learning purposes is enough to understand the concepts right, and worry about compiler optimizations later

Comment: Turns out, [Daniel P. Friedman's and David S. Wise's Indiana U TR19](http://www.cs.indiana.edu/cgi-bin/techreports/TRNNN.cgi?trnum=TR19) "Unwinding stylized recursions into iterations" of ***Dec. 1974*** (revised ***Dec. 1975***) predicts **TCO** (cit. *"obviating the need for a stack"*) and describes **TRMCO** in full detail, all but naming it!! (cit. *"the only operation performed later is the application of the constructor"*).